# How to assign unique variable in python for each line from shell output

Tags: python-3.x

My Python script runs shell command to get lists of values from `oci db vm list` command and it is expected to return 1 to 8 rows depends on size of the VM shape.
i want to assign python variable for each line that is listed from `oci db vm list` from shell

For Example:
The below program returns 2 lines and i am just printing them , but not sure how to assign them to variable.

```
def vmclustnodelist():
    global vmclust_nodelist
    vmclustnode1 =  'oci db node list --compartment-id ' + '    '+prim_compartment_id + ' --vm-cluster-id ' + ' '+vmclust_id +  '    --profile' + ' '+region_profile + "| grep dbnode  | awk '{print $2}' |cut -d, -f1"
    print(vmclustnode1)
    stdout3 = Popen(vmclustnode1, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
    vmclust_node_1 = stdout3.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
    vmclustnode2 =  'oci db node list --compartment-id ' + '    '+prim_compartment_id + ' --vm-cluster-id ' + ' '+vmclust_id +  '    --profile' + ' '+region_profile + "| grep dbnode  | awk '{print $2}' |cut -d, -f1"
    print(vmclustnode2)
    stdout4 = Popen(vmclustnode2, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
    vmclust_node_2 = stdout4.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
    print("VM Cluster Node OCID 1 is ",vmclust_node_1)
    print("VM Cluster Node OCID 2 is ",vmclust_node_2)
```

I get the following output

````
VM Cluster Node OCID 1 is  "ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"
"ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxq"
VM Cluster Node OCID 2 is  "ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"
"ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxq"```
````

i want to assign each line to a new variable inside python as follows:

````
VM_NODE_1 = ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa
VM_NODE_2 = ocid1.dbnode.oc1.phx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxq
VM_NODE_3
...
... ```
````

Comment: Could you add complete text of the line `vmclustnode2 =  'oci db cloud-vm-cluster list --compartment-id ' + '    '+prim_compartment_id + ' --display-name ' + ' '+displa>`? I notice it was partially clipped out (based on `display` is shown as `displa>`) due to it exceeding the window's length when accessing from a text editor like vim or emacs

Comment: Updated the complete text

Comment: I notice the command string for `vmclustnode2` and `vmclustnode1` are the same, shouldn't there be a difference in maybe the `prim_compartment_id` value or `awk` to get the first and the second node instead of just getting one node for both variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the nodes ID in a Python list (ex: `vmclust_nodelist`) and get the value of nodes `i + 1` as `vmclust_nodelist[I]`

```
def vmclustnodelist():
    global vmclust_nodelist
    vmclust_nodelist = [None for i in range(8)]
    for i in range(8):
        vmclustnode_cmd =  'oci db node list --compartment-id ' + '    '+prim_compartment_id + ' --vm-cluster-id ' + ' '+vmclust_id +  '    --profile' + ' '+region_profile + "| grep dbnode  | awk '{print $2}' |cut -d, -f1"        
        stdout = Popen(vmclustnode1, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
        vmclust_nodelist[i] = stdout.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
        print("VM Cluster Node OCID ", i + 1, " is ", vmclust_nodelist[i])
```